# After mysql_query, no result output

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select

I have a simple `mysql_query()` update command to update mysql.

When a user submits my form, it will jump to an update page to update the data. The problem is that there's supposed to be some data shown after the update, but it comes out blank.

#### My form

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="scheduleUpdate.php" >

  <select name=std1>
    <option>AA</option>
    <option>BB</option>
    <option>CC</option>
  </select>

  <select name=std2>
    <option>DD</option>
    <option>EE</option>
    <option>FF</option>
  </select>

.......//more drop down menu but the name is std3..std4..etc...
.......
</form>
```

#### scheduleUpdate.php

```
//$i is the value posted from my main app to tell me how many std we have

for($k=0;$k<$i;$k++){

    $std=$_POST['std'.$k];
//if i remove the updateQuery, the html will output.I know the query is the problem but i //couldn't fix it..
    $updateQuery=mysql_query("UPDATE board SET
                student='$std'
                WHERE badStudent='$std' or goodStudent='$std'",$connection);
        //no output below this line at all
        if($updateQuery){
        DIE('mysql Error:'+mysql_error());
        }

    }

// I have bunch of HTML here....but no output at all!!!!
```

MySQL will be updated after I hit submit, but it doesn't shown any HTML.

Comment: NVM. I fix it now...my if($updateQuery) should be if(!updateQuery)........cant believe the little exclamation mark could mean a lot!....

Comment: @Jerry You can post this as an answer and accept it, or delete the question (the link is just above these comments, under the tag list). Edit: Or accept one of the recently-submitted answers that said the same thing

Comment: Then either put that as an answer and accept it, or delete this question

Comment: Wow..you guys are quick. Since jeroen was the first person reply. you got my accepted answer! and +1 to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error handling is wrong; `$updateQuery` evaluates to true on success, so you kill your program on success instead of on an error.

Answer (score 3):

Should it not be:

```
if(!$updateQuery)
```

?

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it should probably be `if(!$updateQuery){` rather than `if($updateQuery){`. I would have expected that you'd see the output "mysql Error:" though.

As an additional note, please read up on SQL injection and sanitising user input, as you appear to be writing vulnerable code.

Comment: The user only needs to select the value, they can't do inputs. Do I still need to worry about Sanitising data?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should always sanitise anything that will go into a database query. Bear in mind that if I want, I can submit POST data to your page that I've generated myself, rather than using your page. That is to say, you can't rely on the POST data being in the "safe" format you designed.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you die only if the query *fails*:

```
if(!$updateQuery){
    die('mysql Error:'+mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your sample form, you should start `k` at `1` in the `for` loop, not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If You execute the code above you will get HTML output that saying "mysql Error:", also your counter variable k should start form one, since the first form element has name std1.